# battery load percentage - concept/definition

Tags: batteries, bluetooth, charging

I have two pairs of bluetooth headsets which are used interchangeably on my smartphone. One of them can indicate the battery level and the other doesn't.

I'm curious to know what this feature is called in order to find more details about it, eventually how it's implemented from a hardware point of view.

The price difference wasn't significant at all, so I'm curious to know why not all manufacturers are implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, and most simply, a battery's voltage is used to determine its charge level.  It's not necessarily the most accurate method, but it is relatively cheap to implement.

Why a manufacturer would choose to not include the function is simple.  Even pennies per unit add up when the goal is to sell millions of something.